# Permissions for Google Docs/Spreadsheets are requested

Tags: android, android-permissions

My manifest has the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.wise" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.writely" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

But in the Play Market I don't understand why the following two permissions appear:

- Google Spreadsheets
- Google Docs

From where do those come from?!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.writely" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.wise" />
```

> Allows apps to sign in to Google Docs using the account(s) stored on this Android device.
>
> Allows apps to sign in to Google Spreadsheets using the account(s) stored on this Android device.

Found it [here](http://androidpermissions.com/permission/com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.writely) and [here](http://androidpermissions.com/permission/com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.wise)